# Convert int16 to 16 big-endian bit binary

Tags: python, binary, int, short

I've got an array of short/int16s that i need to convert to a padded 16 bit-string(?). I've tried using struct:

```
struct.pack('>H', 545)
```

To which i get:

```
'\x02!'
```

Whereas I need something formatted as 16 bits.

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm rather confused and know next to nothing about the binary system.

Cheers

Comment: That string contains two bytes, `0x02` and `0x21`. Those two bytes give you the 16-bit big-endian representation of 545. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *is* 16 bits. `'\x02'` is 8 bits, and `!` is the other 8.

Were you looking for `'0000001000100001'`? If so, you can do that with the [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) function:

```
>>> format(545, '016b')
'0000001000100001'
```

The `0` means "pad with zeros", the `16` means "show at least 16 digits", and the `b` means binary.

If you don't need the zero padding, you can just use `bin`:

```
>>> bin(545)
'0b1000100001'
>>> bin(545)[2:]
'1000100001'
```

Comment: Just to make it more clear: 545 decimal -> 00000010 00100001 binary. 00000010 -> 0x02, 00100001 binary -> 33 decimal -> `!` ascii

Comment: Ah yes, but i need it formatted such that it would be `1000100001`? I need the 'full' representation?

Comment: @JamesBrennan: Do you mean `'1000100001'`, or `'0000001000100001'`? And are you sure you know what you want? Can you give us some context?

Comment: Hi yes! That's it. I wasn't particularly clear. I need the 16 length representation as the binary represents a descriptive representation of the data quality (eg the 4th bit (16?) represents model validity).